# How to pass logs and visualize it as attribute in jaeger or other app

Tags: grails-orm, jaeger

I have a gorm app to visualize traces and I want to pass logs as attributes and be able to visualize it in jaeger tags or another backend.

Does anyone know if is something possible or already have a solution

I tried to pass set logs to gorm config and get that logs but i havent found a way to get it

Answer (score 0):

Jaeger can show events associated with a Span. If you have instrumented your application with OTEL-Java sdk, you can just [add a event using the API](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/#create-spans-with-events). The great part of this is that you will get a log entry which is bound to the trace/span and you will only see log entries for the specific request.

Here is an example where we have added an event in form of an exception, but the event API is not bound to exception scenarios. [image: Example on how Jaeger can display events associated to a span]